# MySQL spatial slowed after upgrade to 8

Tags: mysql, mysql-spatial

After I updated MySQL from 5.7 to 8, spatial functions have become very slow. Specifically, this query:

```
SELECT points3_.track_id AS track_id
FROM waypoint points3_ 
WHERE ST_CONTAINS(ST_POLYFROMTEXT('POLYGON ((34.82041 32.041814, 34.82041 32.158149, 35.47959 32.158149, 35.47959 32.041814, 34.82041 32.041814))'), points3_.point)
```

now uses a full table scan and takes 6 seconds on 500,000 records, while before it took milliseconds.

I have a spatial index on `point` column, but it's not activated even if I enter `force index (point)`

Answer (score 1):

When you upgrade from mysql 5.7 to 8, you have to modify geometry columns to force an SRID.

From the Ref Manual:

> 1. Verify that all values within the column have the same SRID. To
>      determine the SRIDs contained in a geometry column col_name, use the
>      following query:
>
>    `SELECT DISTINCT ST_SRID(col_name) FROM tbl_name;` If the query
>      returns more than one row, the column contains a mix of SRIDs. In
>      that case, modify its contents so all values have the same SRID.
> 2. Redefine the column to have an explicit SRID attribute.
> 3. Recreate the SPATIAL index.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-index-optimization.html